# Lenovo Z570 HDD not visible in BIOS

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

My Lenovo Z570 laptop is acting weird these days.

When I make it sleep or hibernate, and leave it for minimum 30~45 minutes,and try to start d laptop  HDD light will be always ON and windows will not start. Sometimes  blue screen come and suddenly laptop restarts. And then, if I go to BIOS and check for HDD, it will not be there in the Boot options.

[image: Image1]

Later is shows,

[image: Image2]

If I press n hold the power button and make the laptop completely turn off and start it,even then this problem persists. After 2 or 3 tries, Windows starts to boot and evrything will be normal and performance is as it is. No decline at all.

So I even tried to shutdown my laptop and use it after some time, for eg after 30 or 40min. The same problem occurs.

What can be the problem with? Pls help.

---

### System Information

Operating System: Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit (6.1, Build 7601) Service Pack 1 --fresh install

```
      Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2430M CPU @ 2.40GHz (4 CPUs), ~2.4GHz
         Memory: 4096MB RAM
```

HDD : Western Digital 750GB (WDC WD7500BPVT-24HXZT3)

Result of HDD check:
[image]

**Update 17-08-2014**

- I travelled with my laptop in a bus for 12hrs and surprisingly this
  problem disappeared and my laptop started working fine!
- For a safety check, I've taken my laptop to the authorized service
  center and we are unable to replicate the scenario as it was working
  fine. Technician checked with some Lenovo's S/W(PC doctor) and
  concluded that there is no H/W problem. He reconnected and adjusted
  all the cables and returned it to me. To my fate, the problem is back
  again after 2 days :( and it started to appear as frequent as it was
  before!

So what can be the problem! I'm ready to replace any hardware part! But still waiting for the solution.

Comment: seems to me as a hardware related, is the device under warranty still? if yes, go for this, if no then you are free to open it and check if the hdd is connected properly and fixed.

Comment: NO..its not under warranty now :(

Comment: Probably a hardware issue, as @RuslanGerasimov suggested you should check that the HDD is properly connected (sometimes simply disconnecting/reconnecting it can do miracles), otherwise you may hope that the problem is known and a BIOS update is available to fix it, if it isn't the case then you should replace the mainboard.

Comment: @AndréDaniel I agree with your comment about BIOS update. But before thinking the MB is bad I would test the drive on other machines, I believe it could be the drive failure.

Comment: @RuslanGerasimov good point, you should also test with another hard drive if possible.

Comment: I'm not good at removing n placing HDDs for laptops. Better I go to service center and fix this problem. 

But how can everythg work just fine when windows starts.!!??

Comment: @ShivaMothkuri Before you do anything, make sure to **back up any important data**. The drive might be fine: the way you describe the problem makes me think it doesn't get powered properly all the time. The culprit could be a loose cable, or some motherboard issue. To check the drive health you can use [Data Lifeguard Diagnostic](http://support.wdc.com/product/download.asp?groupid=612&sid=3).

Comment: @and31415 thx for d suggestion. I'll download that tool and check my HDD's health.

But if that's a problem with loose cable, the problem should not occur every time. This is so weird that if I use the laptop frequenlt without giving gap of more than 15min its working fine. If I leave it for more than 15min the problem arises :(

Comment: @and31415 I've a exteneded test with the tool u suggested and image is updated in my post. It's showing extended test failed. So, is my HDD about to die and this is the culprit which is causing the problem?

Comment: @ShivaMothkuri When a drive has bad sectors it's not reliable anymore. Are there any files in the `C:\Windows\Minidump` folder? How old is the laptop and the HDD? When was the first time you noticed the problem? If the motherboard, etc. are actually fine, replacing the disk should fix all the issues you got.

Comment: @and31415 there is no folder as such in my C:\windows.Laptop is almost 3yrs old. so is the HDD.
I'm facing this problem from last 10days only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried replacing my HDD with my friend's HDD and found everything working fine!

Got a new HGST 500GB HDD and voila! problem has disappeared.
Will buy casing for my old HDD and use as external HDD till it dies :D

Answer (score 1):

#### Temporary Workaround

I have also been going through the same problem but as a temporary workaround, it just boots fine (and finds the hard disk) every time if you connect it to the charger before turning it on.

#### Further Observations

It's probably not the hard-disk nor the OS (in my case I have tried different HDDs and an SSD, besides trying my HDD in another machine; and I run Linux not Windows).